# Return all results of a loop in a function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, return

I want to loop through an array of objects in a function.

The problem, when I use return, it only returns the first result, in this case `Olaf Kranz`, but I want to return all first and last names like:

```
Olaf Kranz   
Mark Alien  
Cindy Sunsi  
Anna Pitter  
Piet Schmitz
```

```js
var allInfo = [
  {name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age:33},
  {name: "Mark", lastname: "Alien", age:21},
  {name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age:65},
  {name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age:20},
  {name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age:29}
];

function getAllFirstAndLastnames() {
  for (i = 0; i < allInfo.length; i++){
    return allInfo[i].name + " " + allInfo[i].lastname + "\n";
  }
};

document.write(getAllFirstAndLastnames());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `return`, it immediately terminates the function - you're only going through one iteration. Add to an HTML string instead. Also make sure to use `<br>` for HTML rather than `\n`:

```js
var allInfo = [{ name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age: 33 }, { name: "Mark", lastname: "Alien", age: 21 }, { name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age: 65 }, { name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age: 20 }, { name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age: 29 }];

function getAllFirstAndLastnames() {
  let htmlString = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < allInfo.length; i++) {
    htmlString += allInfo[i].name + " " + allInfo[i].lastname + "<br>";
  }
  return htmlString;
}

document.write(getAllFirstAndLastnames());
```

But this would be cleaner with `.map` followed by `.join`:

```js
var allInfo = [{ name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age: 33 }, { name: "Mark", lastname: "Alien", age: 21 }, { name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age: 65 }, { name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age: 20 }, { name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age: 29 }];

function getAllFirstAndLastnames() {
  return allInfo
    .map(({ name, lastname }) => name + ' ' + lastname)
    .join('<br>');
}

document.write(getAllFirstAndLastnames());
```

Comment: The irrelevant parts look distractive. It's better to condense them into one line when possible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How about `reduce`?

```js
var allInfo = [
{name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age:33},
{name: "Mark", lastname: "Alien", age:21},
{name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age:65},
{name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age:20},
{name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age:29}
];

function getAllFirstAndLastnames() {
    return allInfo.reduce(function(str, item) {
        return str += item.name + " " + item.lastname + "<br/>"
    }, "")
};

document.write(getAllFirstAndLastnames());
```

If you want to more fancy code with ES6. You can use arrow functions.

```js
var allInfo = [
{name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age:33},
{name: "Mark", lastname: "Alien", age:21},
{name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age:65},
{name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age:20},
{name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age:29}
];

function getAllFirstAndLastnames() {
    return allInfo.reduce((str, { name, lastname }) => str + name + " " + lastname + "<br/>", "")
};

document.write(getAllFirstAndLastnames());
```

Comment: `... str += name + " " ...`  only needs to be `... str + name + " " ...` as we don't really care about setting

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here is a *mapping* operation: You're taking an array with one type of data, and you want to transform it into an array of another type of information. In this case, you have an array of objects describing people (first name, last name, and age), and you want to transform it into an array of full-name strings. This is exactly what the [`map` method of `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is used for.

After you've *mapped* the array of people into an array of names, you can use the [`join` method of `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to splice all the entries into a single string.

For example:

```js
var allInfo = [
{name: "Olaf", lastname: "Kranz", age:33},
{name: "Mark", lastname: "Alien", age:21},
{name: "Cindy", lastname: "Sunsi", age:65},
{name: "Anna", lastname: "Pitter", age:20},
{name: "Piet", lastname: "Schmitz", age:29}
];


// map array of people objects to array of name strings
var allNames = allInfo.map(function (person) {
  return person.name + " " + person.lastname;
});

// write out string of all the names, separated by line breaks
document.write(allNames.join("<br>"))
```

The `map` method is known as a *higher-order function* because it takes another function as an argument. In this case, the function transforms an element of the input array into the corresponding element of the output array. Since the function is only used in that one place, we don't bother giving it a name; i.e., it is an *anonymous function*. If you have a reasonably new browser, it probably also supports the more succinct [arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for anonymous functions:

```
// map array of people objects to array of name strings
var allNames = allInfo.map(person => person.name + " " + person.lastname);
```

Newer browsers also support [template literal strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (a.k.a. string interpolation), which can make this example even more succinct:

```
// map array of people objects to array of name strings
var allNames = allInfo.map(person => `${person.name} ${person.lastname}`);
```